Have hook arrows on the opposite side in commutative diagrams
I want to have the hooks on the opposite side as in the last figure.
The following codes display the first figure, while if I use hook instead of hook', I get the distorted second figure.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
commutative diagrams/every diagram,
A/.style={scale=1, transform shape},
every edge/.style={->, draw, thick, >={Straight Barb}, transform shape},]

\node[A] (A1) at (0, 1.5) {$A$};
\node[A] (A2) at (2.4, 1.5) {$B$};
\node[A] (A3) at (1.2, 0) {$A \amalg B$}; 

\path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]

(A1) edge[commutative diagrams/hook'] node[swap] {} (A3)
(A2) edge[commutative diagrams/hook'] node[] {} (A3);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
commutative diagrams/every diagram,
A/.style={scale=1, transform shape},
every edge/.style={->, draw, thick, >={Straight Barb}, transform shape},]

\node[A] (A1) at (0, 1.5) {$A$};
\node[A] (A2) at (2.4, 1.5) {$B$};
\node[A] (A3) at (1.2, 0) {$A \amalg B$}; 

\path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]

(A1) edge[commutative diagrams/hook] node[swap] {} (A3)
(A2) edge[commutative diagrams/hook] node[] {} (A3);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}



Log file for the second figure:
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 803 (preloaded format=latex 2023.7.20)  27 SEP 2024 20:25
**
(root.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (tikz.sty (pgf.sty (pgfrcs.sty (pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104
(pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(pgfcore.sty (graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
) (graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2018/05/3 Graphics configuration of TexpadTeX
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: texpadtex.def on input line 99.
(texpadtex.def
File: texpadtex.def 2017/10/21 v2.0
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
) (pgfsys.sty (pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17
(pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count87
\c@pgf@countb=\count88
\c@pgf@countc=\count89
\c@pgf@countd=\count90
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21
(pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-texpadtex.def
(pgfsys-texpadtex.def)) (pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count91
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count92
) (pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2018/05/3 Graphics configuration of TexpadTeX
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: texpadtex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) (pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(pgfmath.code.tex (pgfmathcalc.code.tex (pgfmathutil.code.tex) (pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count93
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
) (pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count94
)) (pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
) (pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
) (pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
) (pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count95
) (pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
) (pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
) (pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
) (pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
) (pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
) (pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count96
) (pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)
(pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
)) (pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
) (pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
) (pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) (pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) (pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
) (pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
) (pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (pgffor.sty (pgfkeys.sty (pgfkeys.code.tex)) (pgfmath.sty (pgfmath.code.tex)) (pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
(pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
)) (tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
(pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count97
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count98
\tikznumberofchildren=\count99
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count100
\tikz@fig@count=\count101
(pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count102
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count103
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count104
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count105
(tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex 2015/05/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfarrowinset=\dimen151
\pgfarrowlength=\dimen152
\pgfarrowwidth=\dimen153
\pgfarrowlinewidth=\dimen154
) (tikzlibrarycd.code.tex (tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex 2013/07/12 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.4)
) (tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex 2014/03/21 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (root.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 12.
[1

] (root.aux) )


Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Can you show the code+log file for your second figure?

With (A1) edge[commutative diagrams/hook] node[swap] {} (A3) (A2) edge[commutative diagrams/hook'] node[] {} (A3);  I get https://i.sstatic.net/ED9EHtMZ.png

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. I'm afraid it might be an error on my editior. (I'm using Texifier)

Please show the code of the second image and the .log file

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have added the .log file.

Can you edit the code so that it reproduces the second figure for you?

I'm not sure why loading the cd library and not use it.
Mixing styles is the problem with your code.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em,row sep=3em]
A \arrow[dr,hook] && B \arrow[dl,hook'] \\
& A \amalg B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


Otherwise, use
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  hook/.style={{Hooks[right]}-{Straight Barb}},
  hook'/.style={{Hooks[left]}-{Straight Barb}},
]
\node (A1) at (0, 1.5) {$A$};
\node (A2) at (2.4, 1.5) {$B$};
\node (A3) at (1.2, 0) {$A \amalg B$};

\path
  (A1) edge[hook] node[] {} (A3)
  (A2) edge[hook'] node[] {} (A3);
\end{tikzpicture}



I still have the same issue using these codes. I think it might be a problem of my editor. I use tikzpicture so that I can have flexible positions.

@LiuZhiyu You have a very outdated TeX system: LaTeX2e <2017-04-15> is seven years old.

Thanks for pointing that out. I've never noticed.
